# Which property stores the controls a GroupBox contains?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a GroupBox control that has a bunch of controls inside, but when I use the .Controls property, it's empty.

Is there another property that stores these controls?

EDIT: Here is the groupbox code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public partial class CustomGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        public CustomGroupBox ( )
        {
            this.OutlineColor = Color.FromArgb ( 5, 5, 5 );
            this.Font = new Font ( "Tahoma", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular );
        }

        Color outlineColor;

        [DefaultValue ( typeof ( Color ), "5, 5, 5" )]
        public Color OutlineColor
        {
            get { return outlineColor; }
            set { outlineColor = value; Invalidate ( ); }
        }

        [DefaultValue ( typeof ( Font ), "Arial, 8.25pt" )]
        public override Font Font
        {
            get { return base.Font; }
            set { base.Font = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint ( PaintEventArgs pe )
        {
            //painting
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the controls have been added at the time you're inspecting the property? The `GroupBox` stores child controls in the `Controls` property, just as any other container control would.

**Edit**

I can't really begin to speculate about the custom control. Obviously it would be possible to create a control with the behavior that you describe, but I can't fathom a reason for it. Just creating a sample Windows Forms project and dragging two buttons into it and calling `MessageBox.Show(groupBox1.Controls.Count.ToString())` from another button presents a `2`, as expected.

Given the code that you've posted for the `GroupBox`, I can't see any reason for this to happen aside from the controls genuinely not being in the `GroupBox`. If you inspect the `Parent` property of one of the controls, what is the value?

**Edit 2**

If you're saying that you have a `UserControl` that contains your custom `GroupBox` and you're trying to place the `UserControl` on a `Form` and put controls insde the `GroupBox` from there, then that won't work. The designer on the form only "knows" about the `UserControl`; it doesn't know (or care) that it contains a `GroupBox` (for one thing, the designer doesn't have access to that variable by default, and neither do you, since it's `private` unless you explicitly change the modifier).

In order to do this *exactly* as you want to, you're going to have to do the necessary lifting to make your `UserControl` a container, but that is a non-trivial amount of work. I would suggest just placing the `GroupBox` on the form directly.

Comment: Yeah I added them in the designer and accessing them in the Click event for the group box. But hat's a custom control that derives from the standard groupbox, maybe that's why? Also when I move the groupbox, all the controls move as well.

Comment: Ok that's strange. The parent of the controls inside my groupbox returns the form itself, whereas other controls inside the standard group returns the group. I don't know what's wrong so I will try with a new custom groupbox that has no code.

Comment: Another update: I just tried it with my custom groupbox and it worked, ok what's the difference? Well I use that groupbox in a composite control and there it doesn't work. Is there a reason why this wouldn't work composite controls.

Comment: Ok it looks like when I move my composite control, the included controls don't move. So it looks like the grouping functionality is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I see the controls property filled in my groupboxes.  Then just grpMyGroupBox.Controls.Item(index).Name to get the name of the controls.  Doesn't make much sense why you wouldn't see them in there.